# I'm Wondering Thread flow between activity and service in android

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, android-activity, service

When I started the service from activity,
Is this a main thread or not?

I'd like to know why my system too slow if I activated service.
So I'm thinking of the service might use main thread.

[Service] - Main Job - onStartCommand

```
for(int i = 0; i < hp.length; i++){
   if(i%10 == 0 && i != 0){
    Log.i(TAG, "total data : "+hp.length);
   }
}                   
stopSelf();
```

Do I use another thread in service flow?
Give me an advice.

Thx :)

Comment: You can determine this yourself by including the thread name in your logcat message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

`Service
    This is the base class for all services. When you extend this class,` **it's important that you create a new thread in which to do all the service's work**`, because the service` **uses your application's main thread**`, by default, which could slow the performance of any activity your application is running.`

**IntentService**
`This is a subclass of Service that uses a worker thread to handle all start requests, one at a time.`**This is the best option if you don't require that your service handle multiple requests simultaneously.**`All you need to do is implement onHandleIntent(), which receives the intent for each start request so you can do the background work.`